# Data points (over time) that are both spatially even and odd

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, repeated-measures, sas

I have a set of data that has both spatially even timepoints (0, 7, 14, 21, 28 days) and spatially uneven (76, 99, 103, 133 days) timepoints. These are bodyweights collected at each of these days, and all the measurements are from the same individuals (N=72). From 76 days a subset of the groups were no longer required, and thus from days 76 - 133 we have reducing numbers of individuals. We have tried doing a repeated measures analysis but all timepoints from day 21 - 133 are significantly different whereas those from 0 - 14 are not. This should not be the case as the individuals were chosen from birth to be LOW (bodyweight 0.7-1kg) or NORMAL (1.6-1.9kg) birthweight individuals. The differences in bodyweight should no longer be apparent from days 99 - 133, due to catchup growth. When we analyse the timepoints individually (aka without repeated measures) we see the expected differences. So my quesiton is, why does a repeated measures model not work, when it is the recommended model for analysing these types of datasets.